# Add rewrite_by_lua module to nginx:alpine

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker image nginx:stable-alpine, and i need to use nginx-extras
 in order to use `rewrite_by_lua` directive.
I tried to install it via `apk add --cached` but nothing work.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
RUN apk add nginx-extras
```

This is the docker build logs:

```
Building nginx
Step 1/2 : FROM nginx:stable-alpine
 ---> acc350649a48
Step 2/2 : RUN apk add nginx-extras
 ---> Running in 857246deaaf7
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  nginx-extras (missing):
    required by: world[nginx-extras]
```

Any help would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache nginx-mod-http-lua-upstream

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Hey any idea when i add `rewrite_by_lua` under location `location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {` on my ngix.conf i'm getting an error: unknown directive "rewrite_by_lua"